# Call DLL-functions with variable parameters from C#?

Tags: c#, parameters, function-prototypes

I have a DLL that exports plain undecorated C-symbols and comes with a C header file. The header file defines the exact function prototypes of the DLL. Some of them make use of variable number of parameters:

```
OTHERSDLL_EXT_API unsigned long othersdll_exec_cmds(int *var,...);
```

The parameter list expects pairs of ASCII-strings and integer/char values. The number of these pairs differs depending on what the caller wants to do.

My question: how can I use these functions out of a C# application? How do they need to be defined in order to accept variable parameter lists too?

Comment: So... are you asking how to read C header files, or how to call these functions dynamically?

Comment: have you tried `__arglist`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h0f7c37(VS.80).aspx https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5bb6015c-5d09-48d0-929a-d9243ab24aba/calling-c-functions-with-variable-number-of-arguments-from-c-using-pinvoke?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: Nyerguds: I'm asking how to call these functions from C# dynamically - It's clear for me the C-headers can't be used and I have to write the new C#-declarations for my own

Comment: See this : http://dedjo.blogspot.co.uk/2008/11/how-to-pinvoke-varargs-variable.html

Comment: @PaulF: That's it - thanks!